# Terraform How to iterate n times in one list

Tags: terraform

I want to perform something like this:

```
rules = [
for i in somethings : {
//actions
},
for s in others : {
//actions
}
]
```

I need to get in result one list with the result of few iterated loops. The *flatten* logic I think.
Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is unclear. With for you will iterate n times. What you are showing is two for loops iterating over different set of values, if I read it right. Please add more details.

Comment: Yeah, I need the flattened result of this loops in the *rules* list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really needs flatten
The answer is

```
rules = flatten([[
for i in somethings : {
//actions
}],
[for s in others : {
//actions
}
],])
```